# Git merge differs in log

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I use [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) to see my worktree, and learn how to git branch and merge.

Scenario: I have a working master, but must perform a bugfix.

```
git branch Hotfix #Create a new branch for the hotfix
git checkout Hotfix #Move to Hotfix branch
git commit NowGoodFile.cs -m "Add test tools" #Make changes
git checkout master #Checkout master
git merge Hotfix #Merge Hotfix into the master
```

Step by step of what I would like to happen:

- I have a master - working, but find a bug:

[image]

- I create the branch, `Hotfix`, make my changes:

[image]

- I then merge those changes into the master:

[image]

But this is not what happens when I do the `git merge Hotfix`. I get this:

[image]

What should I write to the `merge into` effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `git merge` makes a fast forward merge when it's possible to. What you expect is a `true merge`, which could be done via `--no-ff` or set `merge.ff` to `false`.

Comment: Do I want fast-forward? According to [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge):  

> ...many developers like to use fast-forward merges... for small features or bug fixes, while reserving 3-way merges for the integration of longer-running features.

Comment: @RasmusBækgaard it depends. I personally prefer fast forward merges and always try to make a linear history for the release branch.